# Firestore querysnapshot returning nil swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the number of documents inside of my collection. Here is my code:

```
let query = btRef
        .whereField("UID", isEqualTo: UID)
        .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThan: startOfDate)
        .whereField("timestamp", isLessThan: endOfDate)

query.getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
    if (querySnapshot?.count)! > 0 {
        Variable = true
    }
    else {
        Variable = false
    }
}
```

However, everytime I run it, the following line results in error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

```
(querySnapshot?.count)! > 0
```

I can't seem to find the solution. I know that I am getting this error due unwrapping a nil value. So why is querySnapshot returning nil? Shouldn't it return 0 if there are no documents within this query?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if `querySnapshot` exists and there are no documents, the count will be 0. However it's likely in your case that `querySnapshot` is the nil you're force unwrapping. I recommend unwrapping it using a guard statement before trying to use it. You may also want to unwrap the error so you can print it and see why the `querySnapshot` is nil.

```
query.getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print(err.debugDescription)
        return
    }
    guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else { 
        // handle the error however you like here
        return 
    }
    if (querySnapshot.count) > 0 {
        Variable = true
    }
    else {
        Variable = false
    }
}
```